# How to filter woocommerce order with category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, orders

I want to filter orders by category of products, what I have tried based on research is :

```
$filters = array(
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_type' => 'shop_order',
'posts_per_page' => 200,
'paged' => 1,
'orderby' => 'modified',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query'=>$meta_query,
);

$key="product_cat";
$value=56;//here i am passing category id
$query_cat = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
$meta_query[] = $query_cat;
$loop = new WP_Query($filters);
var_dump($loop);
```

But unable to get order filter. Where I am wrong/missing any thing? 
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: why you are not using plugin which is given by woocommerce for this filter : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/

Comment: bcz its not providing order filters.

Comment: I see , kindly ask this question at : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JaydeepPandya Did you ask over there? If so, could you please add a link here?

Comment: @jezmck I didn't get ans there also, and right now it might be deleted by moderator. I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-filter-orders-by-product/